# Why won't the expected records show up?

Tags: filemaker

I have a Portal which is intended to show charity donors who have a monthly donation (an Ongoing Pledge or "OGP") due/expected for the current month. Under Portal Setup, I've checked "Filter Portal Records", and specified a calculation. It shows an "almost" accurate list of results, but some who should be in there, aren't. My calculation field is as follows:

```
Contacts::Currently has OGP  = "Yes"

and

(

Year(Contacts::LastDonationDate)  ≠  Year(Get(CurrentDate))

or

(
Year(Contacts::LastDonationDate)  =  Year(Get(CurrentDate))
and
Month(Contacts::LastDonationDate)  ≠  Month(Get(CurrentDate))
)

)
```

But even if I strip out everything other than the first line, to just indiscriminately list everyone with an OGP, some contacts stubbornly refuse to be listed. The "mystery" contacts in question have their "Currently has OGP" checkbox tied to a value list containing only "Yes", and indeed contain only that value - "Yes".

But they still don't show up.

I've looked into a lot of possibilities and they've all been blind alleys.

Any idea of something I may not be seeing?

Thanks!
Adam

Answer (score 0):

> ... and indeed contain only that value - "Yes".

Are you sure about this? Attaching a value list to a field can mask other data contained in the field.

To make sure the contents of the field are what you think they are, try one or more of the following:

- Perform a find in the field (in a layout of the Contacts table) , using `==Yes` as the criteria. Any records omitted do not contain the exact value "Yes".
- If you have the Advanced version, use the Data Viewer to evaluate the expression =

  `Contacts::Currently has OGP  = "Yes"`

In the regular version, you can use a calculation field (defined in the Contacts table) for the same purpose.

- Consider re-indexing the field.

Note that we are assuming here that these contacts *are* shown when all portal filtering is removed (i.e. that the underlying relationship is correctly set up) and that the portal is showing records from `Contacts` (not from another occurrence of the Contacts table).

Comment: Thanks Michael - I've indeed been trying to confirm this, and am about as sure as I can be that it only contains the one value. On another layout, I view the checkbox as a text field and seems to confirm this. I had earlier seen multiple values "stacked" in the field, as per the usual (nonintuitive) "add and subtract from a list" behaviour of checkbox fields - this prob. due to an early error of mine. But now I'm sure it only has the one value.

Comment: As an alternative, I tried changing that 1st line to 'Position ( $$Yes ; $$Currently has OGP ; 1 ; 1 ) >0' - which returns a correct result if used on the same layout - but in the Portal calculation field (with or without prefacing the fieldname with "Contact::", it returns an error: "A number, text constant, field name or “(” is expected here.".

Comment: @AdamAbrams Eyeballing the field is not a sufficiently reliable test. See the edit to my post for additional suggestions

Comment: Again to confirm that the field in question says only "Yes", I did a search in that other layout where the field is "typeable", and typed "Yes"... and the correct records came back. So... why would they not show in the Portal?

Comment: @AdamAbrams  "*I did a search in that other layout where the field is "typeable", and typed "Yes".*" That is NOT what I suggested. Please read more carefully. You need to type two equal signs, followed by the characters Yes, no quotes.

Comment: Michael, our comments overlapped each other - I hadn't seen your edited suggestions when I typed mine. (D'OH! Must refresh the page first!) I will give it a go. Thanks!

Comment: OK, when I unchecked the Filter option, all my Contacts - including the ones who'd been MIA in the Portal - showed up there. And a Find using ==Yes shows the correct records. But, turns out 18 of them are not appearing in the Portal. SO - Reindexing. Do I just turn it off in the field's options under Manage Database, save, then go in and turn it back on? 'Cause I tried that and, er, it didn't make any difference... 8^(

Comment: @AdamAbrams I am afraid I am fresh out of ideas. Which version are you using?

Comment: It's 11.0v4. Thanks for your suggestions. I'll keep digging into this as best I can...

Comment: @AdamAbrams Could you post your file (or - preferably - a reduced version, showing only the problem) somewhere?

Comment: Thanks so much Michael, but is there somewhere I can share it privately, just to be safe? I'd rather not have even a stripped down version of it on a public link... but that may be against the rules here...